# what should I input in this common.Model()

Tags: python, optimization, intel-lpot

I am trying out Intel® Low Precision Optimization Tool.

what should I input in this common.Model, specifically what type of the object?

quantizer.model = common.Model('../models/saved_model')

I am referring the following link https://github.com/intel/lpot

Answer (score 0):

You can pass down a path to support model. For example, a path to frozen pb, or a path to saved_model, or a path to checkpoint.

For more details, please check the function comments in https://github.com/intel/lpot/blob/master/lpot/experimental/common/model.py#L25-L28